# How can I find/modify the type of my virtual network adapter installed with VMware Workstation?

Tags: vmware-workstation

Is there a way to know he type of my virtual network adapter installed with VMware Workstation? From [this VMware KB](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1001805), there are several network adapters for virtual machine. But when I add a new network adapter, I don't see any option to set the types. It looks like Workstation chooses a network adapter for the virtual machine automatically. But I do want to know the type of adapter currently used in virtual machine, or modify its type.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your VMs .vmx file. There may be a line like this:

```
ethernet0.virtualDev = "vmxnet"
```

If not, you can add it. The latest is vmxnet3

You should have a driver for it installed in your guest before changing this.

In the guest, you can look at the PCI device list to see which one is being used.

If the line is not there, I believe the default is e1000.

The default type is initially set when you create the VM, not later when adding interfaces by the GUI. But it can be changed by editing the config file.

Comment: Thank you, Keith. Your answer helps me a lot. Sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 0):

If you change NIC type (PowerCLI or GUI) and re-configure the static IP you get the following error: The IP address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX you have entered for this network adapter is already assigned to another adapter.

If you change it vía PowerCLI, the MAC doesn't change.

You can remove a ghost network adapter:

```
set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1

start devmgmt.msc
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/03/vmware-cambiar-tipo-de-nic-sin-cambiar-la-MAC.html